# Fckeditor file upload CGI error in IIS 6

Tags: iis, file-upload, cgi, fckeditor

I'm getting the error below when uploading files through Fckeditor on IIS server. Its fine with Apache.

> Error in CGI Application
>   The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers.

I read about http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;884764 but the hosting claims that they have made the update.

Is there anything else that I could do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution some time back. Basically the error is caused by .htaccess in the root directory or the directory fckeditor is trying to access. Trying removing it and see if it works.